Extracting Bucket Name and Key from AWS Event Triggered NotifyEvent payload in Cloud trail
I have a Event Bridge Trigger set on a s3 bucket and everytime we upload an object, it triggers a NotifyEvent in Cloud Trail. I am trying to extract the bucket name and key from the payload

Before you submit Trigger on AWS GLUE, you should set job data table properties and other informations.Because web-servers might be record your basic job data or crawlers data.
enter image description here

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can set up a lambda for that:
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Extract bucket name and object key from the event payload
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        object_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
                    
        print(f'Bucket: {bucket_name}, Key: {object_key}')
        
        # Add your custom processing logic here

Why would you use AWS glue for that?
